# Add EJB component to IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ejb, jakarta-mail

I am trying to follow the JavaMail API http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html. At the beginning, it asks me to add EJB Component.

I also have maven spring on my project.

How do I add it to my project?

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-ejb-support.html), add an EJB facet to your module:

1. Open the Module Settings dialog box.
2. With the desired Java module selected, click add.png on the toolbar, and select EJB from the list of facets available for this module.

As a result, a new EJB facet is created. Its settings are shown on the EJB Facet page in the right-hand part of the dialog.

Comment: If you can give me screeshot of each step, it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you read the documentation, it is extremely straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. That was from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-ejb-support.html, right?